# SchemeRegistry and Syntax error on token

Tags: android, syntax-error

I have simple code for the ClientConnectionManager:

```
static BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
final static SchemeRegistry schemeReg = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
schemeReg.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
static ClientConnectionManager conManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeReg);
private static DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(conManager, params);
```

which i think should work, but Eclipse says:

```
Syntax error on token "register", = expected after this token
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong and why Eclipse shows this errors?
Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

[For those who find this like I did but want an answer] The reason the above code is giving you those errors is most likely due to where the following code is located:

```
schemeReg.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
```

You can't call this method from its current context. In this instance you need to move it and call it from an initializer block, the constructor, or an instance method.

See
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html
for a refresher on initializing fields if you need additional help.